# sklearn: How to find out which features are responsible for predicted label?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using **Python's sklearn** for **text classification**. The used classifier is **MultinomialNB** and I feed it with *news paper articles* with classes like *sports, economy etc.*

After training the model, I've used the `predict` and `predict_proba` function to test my model with some selected texts. But sometimes there are really surprising results and I want to find out **why**, means especially that I want to know which features had influence on the result and how much influence – to understand the prediction. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are feature_log_prob_ and coef_ not what you are looking for? The first one is empirical log probability of features given a class, P(x_i|y), while the other translates these numbers into a linear model.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2237

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've recently released a package (https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5) which allows to inspect features; it has support for many scikit-learn classifiers, but not MultinomialNB yet (this is in plans though). If you're ok with using another classifier check the [tutorial](http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn-text.html).

If you want MultinomialNB then you can either wait until it is supported, help with that, or use generic explanation method like LIME. eli5 has an experimental LIME [implementation](http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html); there is also a popular package for that from LIME authors: https://github.com/marcotcr/lime.

Sorry, it is not really an answer because a proper answer is to inspect MultinomialNB coefficients and map them back to features; as of scikit-learn 0.18 MultinomialNB has some issues with that though (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2237), so it should be done carefuly (and contributed to eli5 :D).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but really useful on its own - thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your (helpful) answer. I've changed the classifier to **LogisticRegression** and tried to use ``show_prediction`` / ``explain_predition`` function of ``eli5``. The second parameter is ``doc``, and I've passed a text as parameter. But I get ``X has 1 features per sample; expecting 1019``… In the tutorial they pass simply the text as well and not the feature vector. So what's the thing there? And maybe a second question: Do you know what's the mathematical basis of the weights? How they are calculated?

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas passing text to eli5.show_prediction should be fine if you pass vectorizer as well. As for LogisticRegression, see e.g. scikit-learn docs about that: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression - there are some links on this page; wikipedia also has an article about logistic regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). I'm not sure I can explain it in a short comment in an useful way :)

Comment: A basic way to look at Logistic Regression weights in binary case is the following: you multiply LR weights by feature vector element-wise, then sum them; to get probability compute a logistic function of the result. When sum is zero logistic function (==probability) is 0.5; If sum is > 0 then probability > 0.5 and prediction result it "yes", if results is < 0 then probability < 0.5 and prediction result is "no".

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. :)
If I have to pass the vectorizer as well, how to do this in the case of a Pipeline containing a FeatureUnion with two vectorizers plus some scalers afterwards, that are necessary?

Comment: yeah, FeatureUnion is a bit more tricky. There is a pull request in works to make it easier to use (https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/pull/96), but it is not ready yet. To highlight text and show text 3 things are needed: 1) coefficients; 2) feature names; 3) a way to map feature names back to the text. (1) is handled when you pass a classifier. To handle (2) you need to get feature names from FeatureUnion. If all parts of FeatureUnion have .get_feature_names() methods, then you can pass feature_names=feature_union.get_feature_names() to eli5, and features will be shown in a table.

Comment: If not all parts have feature names then currently you have to construct a list of feature names yourselves. Unfortunately scikit-learn scalers don't provide feature names yet (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6425 issue tracks progress on that), but you can make e.g. StandardScaler subclass with get_feature_names() method which returns feature names of a previous estimator - not pretty, but can get job done. Alternatively, you can build feature names yourselves, by concatenating get_feature_names() results from your vectorizers (make sure features are in a proper order).

Comment: This is not pretty, but scikit-learn guys and gals are working on it, and we're also trying to make it more smooth in eli5. Please open issues at https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5 if you have problems getting it work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an old question. But LIME now supports sklearn you can also use Shapely for interpreting any models

[Link to the python notebook on LIME's github repo](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Lime%20-%20multiclass.html)

[Link to the SHAP library](https://github.com/slundberg/shap).  <<< --- Very cool one. Works with a lot of frameworks and is considered as very robust!